# Is there any javascript/jquery plugin that can help to drag and drop multiple files, and work in atleast FF and IE.

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I was looking for a javascript/jquery plugin that can help me drag files from my desktop or any other location to my webpart in sharepoint. I want it to work atleast in Firefox and IE 6+

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Will Firefox 3.5+ and browsers that supports file api (safari and chrome) you can do this with some plugins, but for other browsers, all IEs there is not such support with javascript. In this case you should use flash or silverlight. try PLUPLOAD, or this http://www.albanx.com/?pid=5&subid=21

Comment: Hey thank you , I tried both the plugins but to success. But I found another plugin that was effective on almost all the browsers ,  http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: yes uploadify also is a good choise. but also my plugin has drag n drop with preview of files